# descargar archivos del servidor con php

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando desde una página subir archivos en pdf y descargarlos. Estos archivos salen en una tabla con su nombre y extensión. He conseguido subirlos, pero se repiten por cada id. Los puedo descargar o borrar, pero lo que necesito es ver uno por fila.

esto es lo que veo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código. Espero que podáis ayudarme.

```
<table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;">Tipo</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($media_files as $media_file): ?>
                <tr class="list-inline">
                <td class="text-center">
                  <?php echo $media_file['file_name'];?>
                        <?php 
                            $fileTmpPath = "uploads/products/".$id;
                            if(file_exists($fileTmpPath)){
                                $directorio = opendir($fileTmpPath);
                                while ($fileName = readdir($directorio))
                                {
                                    if (!is_dir($fileName)){
                                        echo "<div><a 
             href='".$fileTmpPath."/".$fileName."' title='Ver Archivo Adjunto' 
              target='_blank'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></span></a>";
                                        echo "$fileName</div>";
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        ?>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <?php echo $media_file['file_type'];?>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <a href="delete_media.php?id=<?php echo (int) $media_file['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Eliminar">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                  </a>
                  
                </td>
               </tr>
              <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: A primeras parece que tienes un bucle while que recorre todos los archivos del directorio. Pero lo tienes dentro de un bucle que ya itera por cada archivo. Creo que en este caso no necesitas el while.

Comment: Si quito el while, me aparece un documento por fila, pero no me deja imprimir el pdf, me abre una página de error

Comment: El código publicado está incompleto, ya que $media_files e $id no los veo definidos.
Quizás si lo subes entero te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Tenías razón, estaba entrando en bucle y quitando el bucle de if y while he encontrado la solución. Muchas gracias